# How to traverse a char among the vector elements?

Tags: c++, vector

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ebg1.png)

Is there any built-in function that exists to allow programmers to find a single char in a string vector(elements)?

Comment: There is a find() function, but if this is an assignment, the professor would probably prefer everyone to iterate through it

Comment: See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for documentation on `std::string` and its functions. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) for all the fun algorithms in the, well, `algorithms` library.

Comment: I think It's better to place description here instead of place link.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in function that checks for a character in a string among a vector of strings.

However, there are built-in functions for various sub-tasks involved in the process, which you can adjoin together to achieve your goal.

A simple way to achieve what you want would be to iterate over the vector of strings and use `std::find()` on each string to search for the element you desire:

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 

int main() 
{  std::vector<std::string> s;
   s.push_back("Stack");
   s.push_back("Overflow");
   char c; 
   std::cin>>c;
   for(std::string& e:s)
   {
      if(e.find(c))
      { std::cout<<"found"; 
        break; 
      }
   }
  return 0;
}
```